# Obtener token de web api/asp desde java/android

Tags: java, android, json, asp.net-web-api

Hola escribi un *web api* en **C#** para autentican, usando `postman` envió los parámetros y devuelve el `token` correctamente, dejare al final del `post` los parámetros para prueba, e buscado un sin numero de código de para traer parámetros en **JSON** desde un *web api* siempre me envía de regreso el `Código 400 Bad request`, solo quiero conectarme desde **Java** usando el *user* y el *password* para que el server me devuelva el `token` generado para ese login he usado muchos código y aun nada, este es el `token` que logro generar usando el `postman` pero desde **Java** solo logro generar `400 bad request`.

Estoy intentando hacer la autenticación para usarla en una app para **Android**

```js
{
  "access_token": "...",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 86399
}
```

```
url token: http://pedidostf.azurewebsites.net/token  
username : admin  
password : *****
grant_type : ********
```

Este sería el último método que estoy utilizando  para la conexion

```
private class POST extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //     InputStream inputStream = null;
        String cliente = params[0];
        String clave = params[1];
        String json = "";
        try {

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
            builder.url(AppConfig.URL_TOKEN);
            builder.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


            FormBody.Builder parameters = new FormBody.Builder();
            parameters.add("grant_type", "password");
            parameters.add("username", cliente);
            parameters.add("password", clave);
            builder.post(parameters.build());

            Response response = client.newCall(builder.build()).execute();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                 json = response.body().string();
                System.out.println("CONTENIDO::  " + json);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    return json;
}
```

Lo conseguir aquí

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607718/get-oauth-token-from-web-api-to-android

Comment: Hola Heisen, no publiques claves ni tokens, es por tu propia seguridad. Salu2

Comment: el server es de prueba no hay problemas, sera borrado cuando logre realizar esto, gracias

Comment: a mi me respondió

{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type"
}

es decir, La implementación predeterminada de OAuthAuthorizationServerHandlersólo acepta la forma de codificación (es decir application/x-www-form-urlencoded) y no JSON codificación ( application/JSON).

Comment: aqui esta un ejemplo usando PostMan https://s23.postimg.org/z07bis49n/capture.png

Comment: @Maguz ya edite el codigo usando solo application/x-www-form-urlencoded pero nada sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: sigo reciciendo el mismo mensaje de respuesta, debes volver a compilar. En cuanto a la categoria de tu pregunta, dice Android, y acá no hay nada de android, deberias definir que usaras, quizas debas editar el servidor e implementar comunicación del tipo JSON

Comment: @Maguz coloque Android por que es una app en android, al indroducir user y password el va al server a buscar el token con los parametros, ya limpie compile y edite y nada el mismo error, e probado muchos codigos y nada y lo triste desde postman si funciona

Comment: Ok, no hay problema de parte del servidor si es que funciona con POSTMAN, ahora necesito que compartas tu método voley, o ClienServiceWeb que usas para comunicarte con el servidor desde Android. En él debe faltar la definición de application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Recuerda usar el botón editar de la pregunta, para no omitir información que pueda ayudar a otros usuarios a ayudarte a encontrar la solución.

Comment: @Maguz el metodo que postie arriba es el que uso para conectarme al servidor, puedo trasladar el debate a un chat? a ver si te queda claro todos los detalles